# Use a while-loop to loop the list of words that are stored my_list and print the last letter of every word whose first letter is 'A' or 'a'

Tags: python

The text is self explanatory, I've managed to do it with a for-loop, but not with a while-loop. 
I just don't want the answer please, I actually want to understand how to do it. 
Thank you very much!!

```
## A list of words is already stored in my_list for you
## to use to test your program, but your program must be
## written so as to work with whatever list of words is
## stored in my_list. You must use a loop, not separate
## print statements.
##
## For the list of words currently stored in my_list your printout should look like this:
##    k
##    e
##    t

my_list = ['petunia', 'Aardvark', 'elephant', 'apple', 'ant', 'monarch', 'eagle', 'tiger']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a while loop, you would want to create an index variable set at 0. Then you would iterate through the list using that index, until you reach the end of the list given by the length of the list minus 1. The rest of the logic is similar to your for loop.

```
words = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"]

index = 0
while (index < len(words)):
    print(words[index])
    index += 1
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-list-in-python/

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to python, would you mind giving me a example?

```for word in my_list:

    if len(word)== :
    
    break
    
print(word)```

Welp, can't really format in the comments, but as you can see I even messed up my for loop. rip.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Also, is that your for loop solution? If so, the break is redundant. The for loop will already stop when all words in my_list have been exhausted.

Comment: Ahh, so that's what was making me go crazy! 
I tried doing it without break and it would give me what I wanted (not with that current code), and then I wanted to re-do it with break (I didn't know I couldn't use it), and it wouldn't work!
I will stick to the first one I did then! Thank you so much! 
And thanks for your answer too! That took the doubt I was having while doing the (index < len(words)) : ! Have a great night!

Comment: Glad you understood it. Have a great night :)

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, you must create a new variable set to 0 outside of the while loop and increase that variable's value by 1 at the end of the while loop each time it runs. Then, you use that variable to loop through each index of my_list. For instance:

```
x = 0 # Here is where we define the new variable
while (x < len(my_list)):
    if (my_list[x][0].lower() == "a"):
        print(my_list[x][-1]) 
    x += 1 # This is where we add 1 to its value at the end of the loop
```

So, first off, we set x equal to 0 so that we start from the first index of my_list. Then, we perform a while loop to keep looping through each of the indices of my_list (`len(my_list)` returns the length of my_list). Then, we test if the lowercase version of the first character of the string at index x of my_array is equal to "a" (we do lowercase to simplify the number of tests we need to perform). Then, if that is true, we print the last character of the string in my_list at index x (creating a substr that starts at -1 gets the last character of a string, so you don't have to worry about getting the size and all). Finally, we add 1 to x to continue looping. This is basically the same as a for loop, just with extra steps. So unless you're required to use a while loop, I would suggest sticking with a for loop instead.

We have to create the variable like that since (as far as I know) there would be no other way to go through each index of my_list. Hope this helps!